# SimpleDateFormat fails

Tags: java

I'm using the routine below to validate dates in `yyyyMMddHHmm` format. The routine works for all cases except for hour = 02. 
For Example it works for:`201203110000`, `201203110100`.. `201203112300`.

What am I missing? Is this a valid bug in SimpleDateFormat or should I be setting the format explicitly for the class to work correctly. I'm using JDK 1.6.0_24.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SimpleDateFormat dateUtil = new SimpleDateFormat();
    Date parsedDT = null;
    String dateVal = "201203110200";
    String dateFormat = "yyyyMMddHHmm";
    dateUtil.applyPattern(dateFormat);
    try
    {
        parsedDT = dateUtil.parse(dateVal);
        if (!dateUtil.format(parsedDT).equals(dateVal))
        {
            System.err.println("error");
        }
        else
        {
            System.err.println("pass");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran the program and it said "pass".

Comment: @ArunManivannan: Try adding this line just after the creation of the format: `dateUtil.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago"));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't specified the time zone for the `SimpleDateFormat`, and we don't know what time zone you're in - but I strongly suspect that's the cause of the problem. I can certainly reproduce the problem if I change the code to:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateUtil = new SimpleDateFormat();
dateUtil.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago"));
```

In at least some places (including the US), March 11th 2012 was when the clocks went forward - so in [Chicago](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=64) for example, 2am actually *never happened*. Local time went:

```
01:59:58
01:59:59
03:00:00
```

Java doesn't give you much control about what happens when you try to parse a date/time which never occurred, but it's at least not surprising that you don't get the same impossible value back - it may well have chosen the instant when 2am would have taken place without the transition, which would then have been formatted as 201203110300 for example.

As for how you ought to *fix* it - it's not clear where this data is coming from or what time zone you should consider it to come from. Perhaps you ought to set the format's time zone to UTC... we don't know.

I'd also strongly suggest the use of [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) as a much better date/time API than `java.util.*`.

Comment: Setting the time zone to UTC fixed the issue. I need to give it some thought as to whether I can use UTC as the timezone but we at least know what caused it. Thanks for your help!